# How to view large DGML or generate smaller DGML from Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, dgml

I have a very large scaffolded database (> 1000 tables) and have generated the dgml file for it using

```
using (var myContext = new ModelContext())
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".dgml",
                                myContext.AsDgml(),
                                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

When I open the `.dgml`, Visual Studio complains

> The DGML document is probably too large to be be displayed because the total number of nodes and links exceeds 25,000 (i have about 50,000).

I can try to open it anyway (which i do), it doesn't run out of memory but I've left it for several hours.

Is there a way around this?

Maybe only create the DGML for part of the database?

Comment: Do you really need 1000 tables in your DbContext??

Comment: there's 1000 tables in the database and I can potentially be querying any of them, do sadly yes

Comment: Interesting how long takes first execution of `var model = context.Model;`. EF Core has performance penalty for such amount of tables.

Comment: without optimisation several minutes, with optimisation a few seconds.